# What is the fastest way to find an End City in The End dimension?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I finally defeated the Ender Dragon and need to find the elytra. In order to get the elytra, you have to find and End City, but I'm having trouble finding one.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to quickly find an End City, because the generation is entirely luck based. What you *should* do is once you exit the end portal, pick any cardinal direction and just head straight that way, moving to the left and right between islands when you need to cover more ground.

Comment: Small correction, you should choose any direction that isn't headed back towards the main island. (x: 0, z: 0).

Answer (score 1):

End cities usually generate in flat areas, in "midlands" or "highlands" biomes, which are found on larger islands. One may find several cities clustered together, or travel for thousands of blocks before finding one.

According to [Minecraft wikia](https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_City#Generation):

> Unlike other structures, End cities are generated in a noticeable grid. They are **located only in chunks numbered 0-8 ± a multiple of 20**.
> For example one possible "cell" for an End city to be generated in is `x_chunks=0-8` and `z_chunks=80-88` which is equivalent to the coordinates `x=0-128` and `z=1280-1408`.